# Convert string to array of struct in bigquery

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

I have a table with the following structure in bigquery,

| id | description |
| --- | --- |
| ddje33qdn | [{"date": "2022-08-25", "value1": 0.0, "reason": "Competition", "comment": "decline"}] |
| sfv4493a | [{"date": "2022-11-01", "value1": 0.0, "reason": "Test"},{"date": "2022-11-02", "value1": 0.5, "reason": "risk", "comment": "decided"}] |
| kjwdf38sd | [{"date": "2022-01-23", "value1": 1.0, "reason": "asked", "comment": "processing"}] |
| whdjgf723 | [] |
| sfv4493a | [{"date": "2022-11-01", "value1": 0.0, "reason": "Test"},{"date": "2022-11-02", "value1": 0.5, "reason": "risk", "comment": "decided"}] |
| skjfg44dc | [{"date": "2022-1-23", "value1": 1.0, "reason": "asked", "comment": "processing"},{"date": "2022-11-01", "value1": 0.0, "reason": "Test", "comment": "decided"},{"date": "2022-11-02", "value1": 0.5, "reason": "risk"}] |

The description contains an array of json but in string type.

I want to unpack the data into the following table

| id | date | value1 | reason | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ddje33qdn | 2022-08-25 | 0.0 | Competition | decline |
| sfv4493a | 2022-11-01 | 0.0 | Test |  |
| sfv4493a | 2022-11-02 | 0.5 | risk | decided |
| kjwdf38sd | 2022-01-23 | 1.0 | asked | processing |
| whdjgf723 |  |  |  |  |
| sfv4493a | 2022-11-01 | 0.0 | test |  |
| sfv4493a | 2022-11-02 | 0.5 | risk | decided |
| skjfg44dc | 2022-1-23 | 1.0 | asked | processing |
| skjfg44dc | 2022-11-01 | 0.0 | Test | decided |
| skjfg44dc | 2022-11-02 | 0.5 | risk |  |

any suggestions

Comment: hi there, what is the data type of description column? is it record type of stored as string

Comment: description column is of the type string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created the data using CTE, see below query and results. for me this works for given dataset. I am sure there are more cleaner ways to handle this, particularly in `JavaScript` UDF in BigQuery

hope this helps

Query:
The `case` statement there is to handle empty string [] and replace it with array format which then can be understood by the `JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY` function to replace it with `null`

```
with nested_data as (
SELECT id, CASE WHEN description="[]" THEN JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY("[{}]") ELSE JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(description) END as unnested_desc
FROM (
  SELECT 'ddje33qdn' as id, 
  "[{'date_': '2022-08-25', 'value1': 0.0, 'reason': 'Competition', 'comment': 'decline'}]" as description
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'sfv4493a' as id,  
  "[{'date_': '2022-11-01', 'value1': 0.0, 'reason': 'Test'},{'date_': '2022-11-02', 'value1': 0.5, 'reason': 'risk', 'comment': 'decided'}]" as description
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'kjwdf38sd' as id, "[{'date': '2022-01-23', 'value1': 1.0, 'reason': 'asked', 'comment': 'processing'}]" as description
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'whdjgf723' as id, "[]" as description
  )
) SELECT ID, 
  json_extract_scalar(unnested_desc,"$.date_") as date_,
  json_extract_scalar(unnested_desc,"$.value1") as value1,
  json_extract_scalar(unnested_desc,"$.reason") as reason,
  json_extract_scalar(unnested_desc,"$.comment") as comment,
  FROM nested_data, 
  unnest(unnested_desc) as unnested_desc
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I made a small modification to your query and it worked. I just added `unnest(json_extract_array(unnested_desc))` and it worked. Thanks